# how to solve 'Allowed memory size of' error when streaming big files in php?

Tags: php, stream

I have trying to make some "replacement-wrapper" over stream described in this :
[article][1]

But when I tested it with not so big file (about 120M) it showed me an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65011744 bytes) in C:\Apache22\htdocs\tuts\php\streams\filters\HiddenNameFilter.php on line 28
```

Here is my wrapper:

```
class HiddenNameFilter extends PHP_User_Filter
{
private $data;
private $limiter;

function onCreate()
{
    $this->data = '';
    $this->limiter = 2;
    return true;
}


function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
{
    while($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in))
    {
        $this->data .= $bucket->data;
        $this->bucket = $bucket;
        $consumed = 0;
    }
    
    if($closing)
    {
        $consumed += strlen($this->data);
        $pattern = "/Andrii/m";
        $str = preg_replace($pattern, '0_+', $this->data);
        $this->bucket->data = $str;
        $this->bucket->datalen = strlen($this->data);

        if(!empty($this->bucket->data))
        {
            stream_bucket_append($out, $this->bucket);
        }

        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }

    return PSFS_FEED_ME;
}
```

}

Here is my сlient code:

```
$handle = fopen(__DIR__ . '/big_file.txt', 'r');

stream_filter_register('myFilter', 'HiddenNameFilter');

stream_filter_append($handle, "myFilter");
$i = 0;
while($i != 30)
{
    $email = fgets($handle);
    if(!$email) break;

    $i++;
    $contents .= $email;
}
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
```

Also I have found some PHP bug [here][2] but I dont know how to solve my problem.

I have PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2019 14:34:10) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
On windows 10/
Please help)
[1]: https://stackify.com/a-guide-to-streams-in-php-in-depth-tutorial-with-examples/
[2]: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/php-custom-stream-filters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add your php code header

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini, exists a parameter to limit memory, find the default php.ini your php is using, and search for "memory_limit" variable. It can look like this:

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

Even if 120M is not so big, you may have a lower limit by default.

Comment: Have you tried to run client code without this line stream_filter_append($handle, "myFilter");?

Comment: I think the purpose of stream is to manipulate data without opening whole file and etc... And without applying filter "stream_filter_append($handle, "myFilter");" it  works perfectly... so I am in process. May be I don`t undersand what the bucket is and hou to use it. Thank you for advise